# WCF Custom User Identification

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I'm creating a server/client solution with custom user logins (not WindowsIdentity). I need a way to transfer the identification over WCF from the client to the server. This is done after the user is authenticated and authorized by the server. I don't want to have the username as a parameter on the service call. I know I can use MessageInspector to add the username to the header, but isn't there another and better way doing this?

Hope I have made my self clear enough.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into **Claims-based Identity** using [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) (WIF).

Comment: I have taking a look at that and I think its a to big solution for my small problem. I think I will use messageinspectors.